# Android TV Apps Searchable (global search) using Online API possible?

Tags: android, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv

I am working on an Application for Android TV and I have implemented in-app search using online API. Is that possible to make Android TV Home screen search/Global search using restful API and display data in the search result rows.

It seems Youtube and Hulu is returning search result which is coming from the feed and not from the data stored by the application. (I am not really sure but seems like it. )

If that is possible, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is possible to do that, although I don't really know how it's done.

Comment: Google Docs doesn't specifically mention this feature. Have you tried [Searching Within Android TV](http://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/in-app-search.html)?